# Wordpress discontinuity between Excerpt and its 'more-button'

Tags: css, wordpress, customization

I'm building a custom Wordpress theme.In my index.php page i'm looping to display the excerpts for all of my blog-posts.

this is how I break the post flow:

```
//At first I place <!--more--> in my post-text where I want to break it..

the_content('more');
```

Now the point is I'd like to place the 'more' button not right after the excerpt.I'd like to place this button in another div containing other link-buttons (tags,comments-count ecc).

[image]

The only thing I came up with is using a span around the 'more' button (with absolute positioning).

Is there any  better solution?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1):

The fact that WP injects the read more link into excerpts, rather than just giving the formatted excerpt, has always been a problem for me, too.  Especially since what surrounds the link is dependent on where the author placed it: inline or on a new line, before or after an image, inside or outside inline markup.  Here's what I've done in the past -- I'm not sure whether this is the best solution but it should work...

- get the raw, unformatted post content: `$content = $post->post_content`
- get the excerpt by using `explode("<!--more-->", $content)`.
- run the excerpt through the `the_content` filter: `$excerpt = apply_filters("the_content", $content[0]);`
- Balance the tags... `$excerpt = force_balance_tags($excerpt)`

On the whole, a better solution may be to ask authors to provide a text excerpt to go with each post rather than relying on this kloodgy method.

Comment: Thanks Chris but I think this time I go for absolute position ..quicker!=)